# JMapViewer, get the OSM map scale, Java

Tags: java, scale, jmapviewer

In my Java application I am using JmapViewer; the map is drawn on the jPanel. Is it possible to get the map scale corresponding to the current zoom level? The map is based on the well-known Mercator projection:

```
X = R * lon * cos(lat1);
Y = R * log(tan(lat/2 + 45)), lat1 = 0;
```

The projection is conformal, so the local linear scale is independent of the direction. My idea uses two points sharing the same parallel:

```
 Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
 Point p2 = new Point(100,0);

 final double dlon = getPosition(p2).getLon() - getPosition(p1).getLon();
 final double scale = 6380000 * abs(dlon) * PI / 180 / 100;  //scale = (R * dlon)/||p1-p2||
```

An improvement: the initial point p1 may be a center of the view.

```
Point p1 = new Point(jPanel1.width()/2,jPanel1.height()/2);
Point p2 = new Point(jPanel1.width()/2  + 100, jPanel1.height()/2);
```

The pixel coordinates are evaluated "in meters"; the formula lacks the pixel size...

Comment: Repost it as algorithm question independent of Java, JMapViewer, JPanel etc. You have Lon/Lat coordinates and the Mercator projection and you want to compute a projection onto a pixel box of width dx and height dy. Add zooming aspect to the question, that is you would have a zoom center point and a scale factor. The rest is irrelevant. In the current form you will most likely get no sensible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`JMapViewer`](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/doc/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/JMapViewer.html) method [`getMeterPerPixel()`](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/doc/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/JMapViewer.html#getMeterPerPixel--) returns the number of meters per pixel at the current zoom level. It uses `TileSource::getDistance`, which "Gets the distance using the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines)." In `org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.Demo`, you can see how the value varies inversely with the zoom; level 10 and 98.5 meters/pixel are shown below. See `OsmMercator::getDistance` for a typical implementation.

[image: map image]